# Can I use FLP without default model ?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

My json model url is `'/destinations/XXX/Collection?time=' + (+new Date)` I don't know how to configure it in minifest of Component.js , so I delete the sap.app.dataSources and sap.ui.models."" (the defalut model? ) , and the flp app gave me this error:

> Failed to load U5 component for navigation intent
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'metadataLoaded' of undefined
>   sap.ushell.renderers.fiori2.Shell.controller

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a couple of links that should get you up and running (I am assuming you are developping on webIDE in SAP HCP (is that correct?)):

[How to setup destinations](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?5c3debce758a470e8342161457fd6f70.html), you need extra properties: WebIDEUsage = odata_gen and WebIDEEnabled = true.

You should then go into your manifest.json and choose Descriptor Editor and choose Data Sources and under OData Services choose the + to add your service.

More information on manifest.json you can find here: [Documentation on Manifest](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/74038a52dcd7404e82b38be6d5fb1458.html)

Comment: Thanks , yes , I am developping on webIDE in SAP HCP . I changed the odata model to json model in the manifest.json , it worked.